# React/Redux how to update state in component through onClick through reducer, then update it in the container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi I am learning redux and working on a project on the side just as practice. I've been struggling to pass the actual information from an action to my reducer and eventually my state. Hopefully anyone can point me as to where I am messing up (probably many places).

This is my list of buttons.

```
{this.prices.map((item, key) => {
                    // this will store the price and name of clicked item
                    // on the _data object above for use in other components.
                    {this.data._data.itemName = item.name}
                    {this.data._data.itemPrice = item.price}
                    return (
                        <TableRow key = {key} >
                            <TableRowColumn 
                                className="exam-cells">
                                {item.name}

                            </TableRowColumn>
                            <TableRowColumn className="price-cells" >
                                <RaisedButton 
                                    key={item.id}
                                    label={item.price}
                                    primary={true} 
                                    style={style}
                                    type="submit"   
                                    onClick={this.props.addPrices}
                                    />
                                    $
```

Now these are my actions (WIP):

```
export const addPrices = price => {
console.log(price)
return{
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_PRICES,
}
```

}

And my reducer:

import * as ActionTypes from '../actiontypes/ActionTypes'
import prices from '../components/PriceEstimate'
import data from '../data/data'

```
const initialState = [
    {   
        name: '',
        total: 100
    }
]

export default function Action( state=initialState, action ) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.UPDATE_ESTIMATOR:
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    total: state[0].total + state[0].total
                }
            ];
        case ActionTypes.CLEAR_TOTAL:
            return [
                {
                    total: 0
                }
            ]
        case ActionTypes.DATA_COMM:
            return [
                {
                    state
                }
            ]
        case ActionTypes.ADD_PRICES:
        return [
            {
                total: state[0].total + {item.prices} ,
        ]

        default: {return state};
    }
}   
  // ideally what I think I need is to add the {item.prices}  

this is my container file:

    return (
      <div className="App">
      <div className="header-container">
        <img src={require('../SmallLogo.png')} alt="logo" id="logo" />
        <div className='price-container'>
          {this.props.total}
        </div>
         { clearComponent }
      </div>
        <div className="main-container">
          { priceComponent }
        </div>
        {/* <aside></aside> */}
      </div>
    );
  };

}

function mapStateToProps (state)  {

  return {
      name: state[0].name,
      total: state[0].total
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

{item.price} comes from a separate file where I have a JSON with an [objects]. My idea is that where I have {this.props.total} to display the actual total from add prices. But I can't seem to trigger that when the button is pressed its value gets added to the previous state. Thus showing the sum of both states.

I hope my explanation is clear about my issue, if not I would likely go into more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I begin, feel free to correct me if I misunderstood anything here, and I'll make an edit.

First off, when passing callbacks to props, you can use an arrow function to send arguments along with it. So in your button list, here's how you'd send the price of the associated button to your addPrices action on click:

```
<RaisedButton
  onClick={() => this.props.addPrices(item.price)}
  // other button props...
/>
```

Next, have your `addPrices` action add the `price` along with the action object that it returns:

```
export const addPrices = price => {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_PRICES,
    price,
  }
}
```

Then, in your reducer, use the `price` on the given action to update the state accordingly:

```
case ActionTypes.ADD_PRICES:
  return [
    {
      // don't forget to include the current state when updating it
      ...state[0],

      total: state[0].total + action.price,
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @kingdaro! I've been stuck on this for a couple of days. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sure! Another small tip: here it might be simpler to make your state a single object instead of an array with one object in it. Though I'm guessing you're future-proofing to have multiple items

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Since the data translates into a list with name and prices it is easier for me to iterate over all of those when creating a table. Later I will use the name within the state. But I do appreciate the help. At the moment every time I add a price it just adds one after another in a list. What I need is basically to concatenate that list to get a total. Would you recommend pushing the values into an array? Regularly for work, I would push it into a _private object to reuse later, however, react is complaining when I try to do this within a constructor. @kingdaro